# What are xmlns=[some url] attributes in the beginning of WPF xaml files for?

Tags: wpf, xaml, url

I noticed in the beginning of a xaml we have stuff like

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

The only other usage I see for xmlns is importing namespaces from my assemblies. Are these also instances of importing assembly? From a URL? If not, what do they refer to? What if the computer is not connected to the internet?

Answer (score 2):

this is not related to xaml, but to xml in general.

The target of namespaces is to be able to uniquely identify xml objects.

take a look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/).

For example, it allows to have two "Customer" node, with different namespaces. Programs can then distinguish if it's a customer node from system A or system B.

This can be compared to C# namespaces also. The "Control" class exists both in System.Windows and System.Windows.Forms and even in System.Web.Ui... same name, but "ownership" are different according the namespaces.

One thing to know, it's only a declaration. the namespace is a freetext, the http:// format is just a convention, and no download of the target uri will occur.

Comment: My question is about the presence of the urls, not about the xmlns itself. If the urls are just convention, what are http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml and http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation referring to?

Comment: I suppose the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml` relates to the xaml parser (as xaml is not only XML, but a declarative language), and the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation` is probably hard-coded somewhere in the WPF library. But it's only a guess

Comment: @Louis: It's for exactly the same reason we place our classes into different namespaces.  In XML, URI's are [how they are named](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_names).  Even though it looks like a URL, it doesn't necessarily have to refer to an existing location.  It's just a name.

Answer (score 0):

The first declaration maps the overall WPF client / framework XAML namespace as the default:

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

The second declaration maps a separate XAML namespace, mapping it (typically) to the x: prefix.

xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

The relationship between these declarations is that the x: prefix mapping supports the intrinsics that are part of the XAML language definition, and WPF is one implementation that uses XAML as a language and defines a vocabulary of its objects for XAML. Because the WPF vocabulary's usages will be far more common than the XAML intrinsics usages, the WPF vocabulary is mapped as the default.

The x: prefix convention for mapping the XAML language intrinsics support is followed by project templates, sample code, and the documentation of language features within this SDK. The XAML namespace defines many commonly-used features that are necessary even for basic WPF applications. For instance, in order to join any code-behind to a XAML file through a partial class, you must name that class as the x:Class attribute in the root element of the relevant XAML file. Or, any element as defined in a XAML page that you wish to access as a keyed resource should have the x:Key attribute set on the element in question

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx

Comment: I think for the benefit of the readers, it's better if you write or quote something that you think answers the question, rather than just giving a link and let the readers find the answer. Especially when the link is not at all succinct.